# ListView doesn't update when underlying object changes

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm having an issue with a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211837.aspx) not showing the latest details of the objects in its dataSource. The dataSource is created by calling the [createSorted method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700743.aspx) of a WinJS.Binding.List object. Each object looks like this:

```
var obj = {
    title: 'First item',
    priority: 2
};
```

And I create/set the dataSource like this:

```
sortedItemList = itemList.createSorted(function (lhs, rhs) {
    return rhs.priority - lhs.priority;
});
listView.itemDataSource = sortedItemList.dataSource;
```

The itemTemplate for the ListView looks like this:

```
<div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div>
        <h4 data-win-bind="innerText: title"></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

The change handlers for both fields look like this:

```
titleControl.onchange = function () {
    curItem.title = titleControl.value;
    sortedItemList.notifyMutated(sortedItemList.indexOf(curItem););
};
priorityControl.onchange = function () {
    curItem.priority = priorityControl.value;
    sortedItemList.notifyMutated(sortedItemList.indexOf(curItem););
};
```

The documentation for createSorted says to be sure to call notifyMutated whenever an object changes. If I change the priority, then the ListView will move the item appropriately. But if I edit the title, then the ListView doesn't update to show the new title. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the ListView doesn't explicitly rebind its elements when notifyMutated on its underlying dataSource is called. If the call to notifyMutated causes an element to be moved, then it will be rebound because the elements are destroyed and recreated. Otherwise, you need to cause the re-binding to happen. My change handlers now look like this:

```
var notifyMutated = function () {
    var prevIndex,
        postIndex;

    prevIndex = sortedItemList.indexOf(curItem);
    sortedItemList.notifyMutated(prevIndex);
    postIndex = sortedItemList.indexOf(curItem);

    if (postIndex !== prevIndex) {
        WinJS.Binding.processAll(listView.elementFromIndex(postIndex), curItem);
    }
};

titleControl.onchange = function () {
    curItem.title = titleControl.value;
    notifyMutated();
};
priorityControl.onchange = function () {
    curItem.priority = priorityControl.value;
    notifyMutated();
};
```